# formula to count blocks meeting a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date range for the last 12 months and below that for each customer is either a "on" or "off" value. I am basically looking to count for each "off" period of many days they were of benefit before going back on.

Example

```
Col A        01/01/2014      02/01/2014     03/01/2014   04/01/2014  
1               off              off           on            off
2               on               off           off           off
3               on               on            on             on
```

So basically at end of each row of dates I want another six columns block 1 to block 6 (block 6 will always be the max) So for the above ID 1 was off benefit two days then back on and off again, so I want the columns at the end to look like:

```
Col A         Block 1      Block 2      Block 3      Block 4      etc etc 
1                 2           1            -             -
2                 3           -            -             -
3                 -           -            -             -
```

For each time they go back on benefit and then come back off that starts a new block. Is there any easy way of doing this? I have nearly 800k of rows and really really don't want to do this manually

Comment: would the 6 blocks be of the latest benefit status in the last 12 months, or the earliest??

Comment: I guess you could do it with a formula with some helper columns, don't know how speed would compare with UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do it myself using a array formula, I don't understand UDF enough at moment to use the previous answer.

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(($A3:$OF3="Off")*($B3:$OG3<>"Off"),COLUMN($B3:$OG3),""),OJ$1)-SMALL(IF(($A3:$OF3<>"Off")*($B3:$OG3="Off"),COLUMN($B3:$OG3),""),OJ$1),"")
```

This seemed to work with a helper column of 1 to 6

I've checked the results on close to 6000 rows of data and seems to work perfectly not found any issues at moment.

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following user defined function to acheive this result.

If you are not familiar with UDF, you can follow this tutorial :

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel

```
Function CountBlock(v As Variant) As Variant
    Dim output(1 To 6) As Variant
    Dim cell As Variant

    Dim count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1

    For Each cell In v
        If cell = "off" Then
            count = count + 1
        ElseIf i = 6 Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf count > 0 Then
            output(i) = count
            i = i + 1
            count = 0
        End If
    Next

    output(i) = count
    CountBlock = output

End Function
```

Result will be outputed as an array so you'll have tu use an "array formula" of 6 items. Just select 6 contiguous cells.  Then write `=CountBlock(B2:E2)` and do `control+Enter`

Comment: I envisage a possible 'subscript out of range' error  here